# ¿Como hacer Truncate Table con Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Buen día, tengo una consulta ¿De qué manera puedo hacer un truncate a una tabla por medio de Linq?
El siguiente comando no funciona:

```
context.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Entity");
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Eso no es Linq, supongo que te refieres a Entity Framework (EF). Me parece que no existe truncate en EF, pero podrías intentar algo como context.Tabla.RemoveRange(context.Tabla.ToList()); Aunque seguramente el performance será una mier.. malo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Truncate Table MiTabla");
```

De esta forma puedes utilizar **EntityFramework** para ejecutar cualquier comando en **SQL** puro.

Abundando más sobre el comando **Truncate** te recuerdo que es un comando de tipo **DDL**, en español **Lenguaje de Definición de Datos**, otros comandos de tipo **DDL** son **Create**, **Drop**, **Alter** que se pueden usar para **tablas**, **vistas**, **procedimientos almacenados** y **triggers**.

Existen también los comandos de tipo **DCL** o **Lenguaje de Control de Datos**, por ejemplo **Grant** y **Revoke** que se emplean para otorgar o eliminar permisos a los usuarios del gestor de base de datos.

También están los comandos de tipo **DML** o **Lenguaje de Manipulación de Datos**, aquí se encuentran los comandos **Select**, **Update**, **Insert**, **Delete**.

Por último decir que si tú tabla tiene llaves foráneas con otra tabla el comando **Truncate** no se ejecutará ya que se violaría la integridad referencial lo que causaría inconsistencia en la información.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fuiste de gran ayuda :)

Comment: Hola Daniel, si la respuesta resolvio tu problema podrias marcarla como aceptada, gracias